Facebook Graph API - Get Page Commets
I'm working on a Facebook integration and need to retrieve comments from posts on any public Facebook Page (not just Pages I manage) using webhooks.
My app type is currently set to Consumer. I read that switching to Business might help, but I’m not sure if that alone will grant broader permissions.
1. What are the steps to follow to request access to public page comments for any Facebook Page?

What app type should I create in the Facebook Developer Apps section, and which specific permissions should I request?

3.Can I convert my app type from Consumer to Business, and if I do, will that allow access to comments on any public Page?
4. How can I add a page to my app to receive comments via Webhooks for Pages I don’t manage?
What I’ve Tried:

My app type is currently set to Consumer. I read that switching to Business might help, but I’m not sure if that alone will grant broader permissions.

I’ve requested pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_engagement, but they only seem to work for Pages that the app or user manages.

Looked into Public Content Access, but the guidelines are unclear on how to access comments specifically.



You can only get webhook updates for pages you have admin access to.

If a user grants my app access using their user token, will I be able to integrate the page's webhooks into my app?

Sure, as long as they have sufficient capabilities on that page.

Thank you for your answer.
Is it possible to add a user's public pages to my webhook using their permission and token? If so, how can I do this?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/accounts/ gets you the list of pages the user has a role on, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v21.0/app/subscriptions explains how to do the webhook subscriptions.
